# C program to shift items in a stack built using a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I am trying to roll the first 3 elements of a stack being implemented as a linked list. For example if the stack were: 1 2 3 4 5 before being rolled. After the roll function it should be: 3 1 2 4 5. The third item goes to the top of the stack and everything else is shifted one position down in the stack. Here is what I have been playing with for the roll function:

```
// roll function rolls the top 3 numbers on the stack
struct item *roll(struct item *top){
        struct item *cur = top;
        struct item *prev = NULL;
        int i = 0;
        // get cur and prev to point to proper positions in linked list
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->next;
        }
        // roll the linked list
        prev->next = cur->next;
        cur->next = top;
        top = cur;

        return top;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in your code?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: When i run it does not work properly. The result is the linked list in the same order but is missing the last item. I'd like some pointers as to where i might be going wrong.

Comment: Pop the first three elements. Then push the second, first and the third.

Comment: Is your data structure a circular linked list or an actual stack in which the bottom element has `.next==NULL`?

Comment: It is not a circular linked list

Comment: you could cheat ;) just swap the content of first element with the third one :)

Comment: That wouldn't work. That would make 3 2 1 4 5 instead of 3 1 2 4 5.

Comment: I do not think it will be `3 2 1 4 5` [mcve]

Comment: The operation proposed would not be treating the linked list as a stack. Another container (which could be another stack) will be needed to hold the values popped from the stack in order to get to the target element, remove it, push the original values back, then push the target element.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should run n-1 times

```
struct item *roll(struct item *top){
    struct item *cur = top;
    struct item *prev = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    // get cur and prev to point to proper positions in linked list
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
    }
    // roll the linked list
    prev->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = top;
    top = cur;

    return top;
}
void print()
{
struct item *temp = roll(top);
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
    cout<<temp->value;
    temp=temp->next;
  }
}
```

Output

```
31245
```

Comment: not sure why but with this change, my code is still giving the same problem as before

Comment: Either you made a mistake while creating or while printing. Upload your whole code.